# SRS server, DVR doesn’t work correctly with WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, srs, simple-realtime-server

I'm testing SRS on my server. I have a problem when using DVR to save WebRTC to an mp4 file. The mp4 file only has some seconds, not full time (sometimes it only has 1 second). Do you have any suggestions for my case?

Answer (score 0):

For the feature WebRTC DVR, SRS converts WebRTC to RTMP, then DVR RTMP to FLV or MP4 file.

WebRTC video stream changes the SPS/PPS now and then, which means there would be more than one SPS/PPS frame, actually there is one before each keyframe.

It works well for DVR WebRTC to FLV file, because FLV supports SPS/PPS change. But for MP4, it fails because it doesn't support SPS/PPS change.

There is a solution:

1. DVR WebRTC to FLV file by [SRS](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/dvr).
2. Setup the [on_dvr](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/dvr#http-callback) http callback, so that your server can handle the FLV file.
3. Your server starts a FFmpeg process to transcode the FLV file to MP4.

> Note: Here `your server` is not SRS, but your backend server. You can write one by Go, and there is [an example](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/http-callback#srs-http-callback-server).

Please note that you should use FFmpeg to transcode the FLV file, not only transmux the format, here is an example:

```bash
ffmpeg -i dvr.flv -vcodec libx264 -profile:v high -preset:v slow \
  -acodec copy -y dvr.mp4
```

Here we transcode the video stream and copy the audio stream, which has already been transcoded from opus by SRS.